# add validation if text field is empty

Tags: angular, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new at Angular and Ionic, I am trying to add a validation in my Alert textbox.
By default, I am disabling the submit icon by css

> ".comment-history-box{pointer-event:none;}"

. I want to remove the property if user has added any comment in the field.

```
async presentAlert() {
  
  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'comment',
        type: 'textarea',
        placeholder: 'Enter your comment...',
        cssClass: 'custom-textarea',
        attributes: {
          maxlength: 60  // Add maxlength attribute to limit character input
        }
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: '✖',
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'secondary',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
          this.openDateTimePickerOverlay()
        }
      }, {
        text: '✓',
        cssClass: 'comment_box_history',
        handler: async (data) => {
          if (data.comment && data.comment.trim() !== '') {
            this.store_user_data.description = data.comment;
            console.log(this.store_user_data);
            this.saveData(this.store_user_data);
          } else{
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you're using alertController once you created and presented the object it isn't possible to change inside datas dynamically.

I suggest you to handle the empty comment error with a toast to make the user understand what's the issue with the comment input

```
async presentAlert() {
          
            const alert = await this.alertController.create({
              inputs: [
                {
                  name: 'comment',
                  type: 'textarea',
                  placeholder: 'Enter your comment...',
                  cssClass: 'custom-textarea',
                  attributes: {
                    maxlength: 60  // Add maxlength attribute to limit character input
                  }
                }
              ],
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: '✖',
                  role: 'cancel',
                  cssClass: 'secondary',
                  handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    this.openDateTimePickerOverlay()
                  }
                }, {
                  text: '✓',
                  cssClass: 'comment_box_history',
                  handler: async (data) => {
                    if (data.comment && data.comment.trim() !== '') {
                      this.store_user_data.description = data.comment;
                      console.log(this.store_user_data);
                      this.saveData(this.store_user_data);
                    } else{
                      let toast = await this.toastController.create({
                        message: "comment not valid",
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: 'top',
                        color: "danger"
                      });
                      toast.present();
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
        
            alert.present()
    }
```

Comment: impossible is nothing :)

Comment: @Eliseo i mean it isn't possible to change **data fired to the alertController**, not that it isn't possible to make it with vanilla js, anyway that's an alternative solution.

Comment: I update the answer to show a typical error message, Sincerely, create a "toast" to show an error is not an idea that like **personally** (it's not bad, only I don't like so much)

Answer (score -1):

Impossible is nothing

You can write a function like

```
 addEvents() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-wrapper')[0];
      const input = alert.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
      const button = alert.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
      input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        button.disabled = !(event.target as any).value;
      });
    });
  }
```

And when you present the alert execute the function.

NOTE: You can also change the css of the button

**Update**

Well, really I don't like so much that the button is disabled until a condition. In my opinion, we should allow user click the button, if the comment is empty we show an error message (or an action to allow the user correct the error. So typical we can define a css (in styles.css) like

```
.alert-input.sc-ion-alert-ios.error {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  background: transparent;
  opacity:1
}
.ng-valid ~ .alert-input-wrapper
{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

And we define two inputs (the last disabled that show the error). In handler of "ok" button, we check and add/remove the class ng-valid, also when change the input

```
  public alertButtons = [
    {
      text: 'OK',
      name: 'okButton',
      handler: async (data) => {
        if (data.comment && data.comment.trim() !== '') {
          console.log(data.comment);
          return true;
        } else {
          const alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-wrapper')[0];
          const input = alert.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
          input.parentElement.classList.remove('ng-valid');
          return false;
        }
      },
    },
  ];
  public alertInputs = [
    {
      type: 'textarea',
      name: 'comment',
      placeholder: 'A little about yourself',
      handler: (alertData) => console.log(alertData),
    },
    {
      type: 'text',
      value: 'Please, add a comment',
      cssClass: 'error',
      disabled: true,
    },
  ];
  addEvents() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const alert = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-wrapper')[0];
      const input = alert.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

      //we add at very fisrt is "valid" to not show the error
      //until a change happens

      input.parentElement.classList.add('ng-valid');

      const button = alert.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

      //when cahnge the input we add/remove the class
      //to the parent (the "wrapper" div)

      input.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        if ((event.target as any).value)
          input.parentElement.classList.add('ng-valid');
        else input.parentElement.classList.remove('ng-valid');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

You can see in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqr8kt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.css,src%2Fstyles.css)

Comment: Nothing is impossible***